# What does this /param/ mean in this mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to understand the following from the mongoose documentation:

```
// With a JSON doc
Person.
  find({
    occupation: /host/,
    'name.last': 'Ghost',
```

What do the / / signify in the above query? I see from the second portion we can query on a literal with quotes - 'Ghost'. If we want to query on a variable name host we could just do host right? So what is /host/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/host/` means that it's a regular expression query: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

To paraphrase the manual, there are four methods to describe a regular expression query in MongoDB:

```
{ <field>: { $regex: /pattern/, $options: '<options>' } }
{ <field>: { $regex: 'pattern', $options: '<options>' } }
{ <field>: { $regex: /pattern/<options> } }
{ <field>: /pattern/<options> }
```

In your example, both queries `/host/` and `'Ghost'` will match the text `Ghost` (`/host/` will also match `hosted`, `hostess`, `co-host` etc.). Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression for more explanation regarding this topic.

However, please note that there are caveats regarding regular expression queries with regard to index use: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use.